# Angular: Is there a way to guess if a scope is transcluded or not?

Tags: angularjs

Hello, for the purpose of my code I need to identify if a particular `$scope` is transcluded or not. Imagine that somewhere inside your code you need to make `.parent().parent()...parent()` and you need to check if the resulting scope is transcluded one or not. Is there a way to do that?

[My goal]
My goal is to make something like:

```
if($scope.isTranscluded()) {
    //do one thing.
} else {
    //do another thing.
}
```

Thank you for your time !!!

Comment: See http://zachsnow.com/#!/blog/2013/angularjs-multi-transclusion/

Comment: if you are having to do `.parent().parent()...parent()` you are doing something wrong

Comment: @charlietfl I am not doing .parent().parent()...parent(). My logics will need some time to explain here, but the logic in this case is irrelevant to the question. Sorry for the messy example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surprisingly, you have an inner private property: `$$transcluded`

So you can check: `if($scope.$$transcluded) {`

However, since it is a private property ($$) you cannot rely on it to not break on future versions.

---

You should also take a look at the source code

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.19/src/ng/compile.js#L976

Comment: Big thanks for the solution! It seems I missed to see that property. As it comes to $$transcluded being private, sadly I know that, but I already rely on some private angular code, so this solution fits perfectly my problem. THANKS! +1.